# Shell_exec doesnt respond to most commands

Tags: php, python, ls, shell-exec

In my controller of my PHP web project. I have line:

```
return shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 blabla/parser.py');
```

I need to run my script which returns RAW HTML, but i receive no responce. I have tried on Windows and it worked. But on Linux it doesnt
If i type:

```
return shell_exec('echo a');
```

i have a response a;

Why PHP doesnt want to output shell_exec even python3 -v?

Comment: Try getting stderr with `shell_exec('ls 2>&1')`

Comment: "ls" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥� ��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Comment: All those garbage characters look like an encoding issue.

Comment: what should i do?

Comment: Why not use scandir() function from PHP ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: i have edited my question. The main problem is executing python script not listing directories. im sorry